# Solve Gegenbauer integral $\int\limits_{-1}^{1} x^k \cdot (1-x^2)^{\alpha-1/2} C_n^{\alpha}(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, orthogonal-polynomials

I am looking for an analytic solution of the integral

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-1}^{1} x^k \cdot (1-x^2)^{\alpha-1/2} C_n^{\alpha}(x) dx
\end{align} where $C_n^{\alpha}(x)$ is a given Gegenbauer polynomial and $k$ is an integer.

A similar integral with integration range from 0 to 1 is calculated here,
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01650571, but I do not see how to calculate it in the range -1 to 1. A related question for Legendre polynomials is also answered here (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244204/legendre-polynomial-integral) , but it also refers to the above paper, which only includes half the integration range, and only the special cases of $k=1$ and $k=2$ are given explicitly. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(-x\right)=\left(-1\right)^{n}C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(x\right)$$ [which can be easily deduced by the explict representations of $C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(x\right)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials), we can simply observe that
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}x^{k}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{\alpha-1/2}C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(x\right)dx= & \int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{\alpha-1/2}C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(x\right)dx \\ + &\int_{-1}^{0}x^{k}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{\alpha-1/2}C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(x\right)dx \\ = & \left(1+\left(-1\right)^{k+n}\right)\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{\alpha-1/2}C_{n}^{\alpha}\left(x\right)dx
\end{align} and now you can proceed as in the paper you cited.

Comment: yeah that makes sense thanks!

Comment: but wait, shouldnt there be a minus sign in the prefactor, so $(1-(-1)^{k+n})$

Comment: @ThorstenGlu It seems to me that the signs are correct; in the second integral one minus is used to invert the extremes of the integral.

Comment: yeah they are correct, I missed the minus from the dx conversion